# Simple OOP/private variable query- Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, object, private

Not quite sure why this won't work, when i try to compile and run it gives me a null pointer exception. I know it's super simple and probably a stupid question but I can't seem to figure it out!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Whatever
{

    private int age; 
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public Whatever ()
    {
        String userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What is your name?");
        Whatever listData[] = new Whatever [10];
        listData[6].name = userName; 
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Whatever testWhatever = new Whatever ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Array of `Whatever` instances - all are `null`.

I would guess you'd have another problem with `OutOfMemoryError` as soon as you fix it, because when you call new to initialize the `Whatever` array elements they'll construct their own arrays and call new, and so on until you get OOM error.

I'll spell it out for you so you can get to the next error:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Whatever
{
    private int age; 
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public Whatever () {
        String userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("What is your name?");
        Whatever listData[] = new Whatever[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < listData.length; ++i) {
            listData[i] = new Whatever();  // This is where you'll get the OOM error.  See why?
        }
        // You'll never get here.
        listData[6].name = userName; 
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Whatever testWhatever = new Whatever();
    }
}
```

And you're putting Swing code in a constructor?  Did you intend this as an example of how to write bad code?

Just for future reference, you should run your code in a good IDE - like IntelliJ, the best on the market - with debugging turned on and step through the code.  You'll figure it out pretty quickly where the problem lies, faster than asking at SO will tell you.

So yes, it's a pretty stupid example.  Hopefully you aren't writing anything like this for real.

Comment: I'm very very beginner haha, what I'm trying to do is assign a value to the "name" field of an element of an array of the Whatever class, but obviously what I'm doing above doesn't work

Comment: I see what you're doing.  Do you understand my answer?  Do you see how this will get you into trouble?

Comment: Ah yes I see the mistake now!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

With this

`Whatever listData[] = new Whatever [10];`

you initialized a new Array, but the elements in the Array are not initialized.

So you get a NullPointerException when you access `listData[6].name`.

You could try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
    listData[i] = new Whatever(); 
}
```

, but please do this not in the constructor itself.
Because then you would get OutOfMemoryException like duffymo said.

Try to do this directly in main for example.